# How can I call a mysql function using MysqlConnector?

Tags: c#, mysql, function

I'm using:

```
MySqlCommand comHash = new MySqlCommand("MY_FUNCTION", con);
comHash.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; // ??
comHash.Parameters.AddWithValue("my_parameter", "value1");
comHash.????
```

I need return the value from function.

Answer (score 2):

I was recently struggling with the same problem. Here is the solution I found.

```
MySqlCommand comHash = new MySqlCommand("SELECT MY_FUNCTION (?my_parameter)", con);
comHash.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
comHash.Parameters.AddWithValue("my_parameter", "value1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you looking for?

```
static void CallProc()
{
 //Establish connection
MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection("user id=root;database=demobase;host=localhost");
myConn.Open();
//Set up myCommand to reference stored procedure 'myfunc'
MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("myfunc", myConn);
myCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

//Create input parameter and assign a value
MySqlParameter myInParam = new MySqlParameter();
myInParam.Value = "Mark";
myCommand.Parameters.Add(myInParam);
myInParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input;

//Create placeholder for return value
MySqlParameter myRetParam = new MySqlParameter();
myRetParam.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
myCommand.Parameters.Add(myRetParam);

//Execute the function. ReturnValue parameter receives result of the stored function
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
Console.WriteLine(myRetParam.Value.ToString());
myConn.Close();
}
```

The function used was:

```
CREATE FUNCTION demobase.myfunc(uname CHAR(20))
RETURNS CHAR(60)
RETURN CONCAT(uname,' works with server ',@@version);
```

Example extracted from [here](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Parameters.html)

Comment: It doesn't works. Error: Key cannot be null. Parameter name: key.

Comment: Are you sending all the parameters to your function?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//
MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand();
myCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
myCommand.CommandText = "FNC_IsUserInSite";

MySqlParameter rv = new MySqlParameter();
rv.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
rv.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int32;
rv.ParameterName = "@retval";
myCommand.Parameters.Add(rv);

myCommand.Connection = connection;
//

myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
object ret = myCommand.Parameters["@retval"].Value;

if (ret != null)
{
    if ((int)ret > 0)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you can use:

```
dataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(myCommand, myConn);
data = new datatable();
dataAdapter.Fill(data);
```